# Uninstalling a program silently - Is there a way to execute rundll32.exe silently via PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, uninstallation, silent, rundll32, uninstallstring

I'm trying to uninstall a Mindspark program using PowerShell. I was able to see the uninstall string for the program is:

```
rundll32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\DailyHomeGuide_bg\bar\1.bin\bgBar.dll",O mindsparktoolbarkey="DailyHomeGuide_bg" uninstalltype=IE
```

Running the command above works, however it requires user interaction. When the command above is executed, it prompts the user "Are you sure you want to remove the program?" **Is there a way to run the command silently?**

I tried looking for a silent switch but no bueno.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, `rundll32` doesn't have a switch to do it itself.  It's not like `regsvr32`.  There would need to be a parameter passed to the library itself.  Check with the vendor.  You could also try `Start-Process -WindowStyle Hidden ...` but that also isn't going to guarantee that no window will open and you'll have to be very particular about how you specify your arguments (it's not entirely intuitive if you're not familiar with it, and the comma can easily cause issues).

Comment: You could try using SendKeys to get around rundll not having silent switches
https://www.jesusninoc.com/11/05/simulate-key-press-by-user-with-sendkeys-and-powershell/

Comment: Did you try `RUNDLL32.EXE dll_name,EntryPoint /?`. It _could_ display all the available commands (and switches)…